# Are there console and startup commands in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

[Previously](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?251759-Console-commands-%28-players-x-etc-%29), you could use console commands to affect certain things about the game you were in, and start up commands allowed for simple changes to the game when launching.  However, I haven't been able to find a similar reference for Diablo 3.

Are these types of commands supported in Diablo 3?  How do you access the console?  Are the commands (or the most frequently used ones) listed somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enter a few commands by prefixing them with a slash in the chat:

> /? List all commands
>
> /c Send text to channel
>
> /chatlist List channels
>
> /who List players of current channel
>
> /p Send a message to the party
>
> /bye, /die, /follow, /give, /go, /help, /run, /sorry, /thanks, /wait - Hero emotes

Ctrl+R in the game will show the FPS

There are also a few command line switches:

> -w The game will run in windowed mode
>
> -launch The game will go straight to the menu.
>
> -auroraddress Lets you specifiy an alternate login server

[D3dev](http://diablo3dev.com/w/Command_Line_Options) also lists these options for which I don't know what they do (nope, no -help):

> -battlenetaddress
>
> -battlenetmatchmakingaddress
>
> -test
>
> -perftestfilter
>
> -perftestwaittime
>
> -perftestsampletime
>
> -perftestdumpfreq
>
> -perftestformat

Comment: Both good answers.  A tough choice, but I went with this one as a more comprehensive list.

Answer (score 7):

Due to the highly MMO-like nature of the game, players cannot alter anything about the match via console.  There are, however, several chat commands and a couple of command-line switches available, although they're not entirely useful (and a large amount were disabled after beta).

A listing of available chat commands can be viewed in-game using the `/?` command.

I cannot find any sources that give a full listing of command-line arguments, but I can confirm two of them:

`-w`

Using this switch will force the game into window mode.

`-launch`

This switch will bypass the updater and get you straight into the game, though I'm not sure how it will react if an update is available.

For example, `"Diablo III.exe" -w -launch` will bypass the update and take the game directly to the login screen using window mode.

I will attempt to keep this answer updated as new information is revealed.