# Takes forever to update tools and it happens every time I turn on for Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

For Diablo 3, when I open the game it says it is updating tools and then updating blizzard launcher. When it is updating the tools it takes at least a half an hour and sometimes doesnt even work. When it does work a message box pops up that says failed to update tools.

The game will then close but if I click on the game again it will just to the updating blizzard launcher step. This process will also take 15 to 20 minutes but once its done I can start playing the game.

Is there any way to fix this? I have windows 7 with trend antivirus.

Comment: actually now it is no longer skipping the updating tools step the second time through

Comment: do you have some form of antivirus running? if so try disabling it's auto protect and firewall during your time running the game.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to update tools](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69911/failed-to-update-tools)

Answer (score 1):

In the answers to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69763/are-there-console-and-startup-commands-in-diablo-3) you can see the "-launch" flag which will bypass the launcher update.  I've tried it and it at least doesn't break anything, but it may have side effects.  It may at least be a stop gap, while you figure out the underlying problem.